# Separated objects following the original one

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When i try to separate objects it all works out fine, but when i wanna **move** the object and **keyframe** the motion of it moving from the original one the original one just follows it. I tried *uparanting*, but it doesn't work. How do i solve this? Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you separated the 2 objects they kept the same animation, and if you change the animation for one it will change it for the other, several objects can share the exact same animation. What you can do is:

- Go in the *Dopesheet*, switch it to *Action Editor*

[image]

- Create an new animation from the previous one (*Create New Action*), or remove all animation (X button).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly!